# Derivative of the $2$-norm of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I've got a function $$g(x,y) = \| f(x,y) \|_2$$ and I want to calculate its derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Using Mathematica, differentiating w.r.t. $x$ gives me $ f'_x(x,y) \text{Norm}'( f(x,y))$, where Norm is $\| \cdot \|$.

I read [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/MathH110/NORMlite.pdf) that

$$d\|{\bf x}\| = \frac{ {\bf x}^Td{\bf x}}{\|{\bf x}\|}$$

at least for the $2$-norm. Point is, as inside the norm I have a multivariate function, I'm still confused on how to calculate $ f'_x(x,y) \text{Norm}'( f(x,y))$

I think it should be $f'_x(x,y) \frac{f(x,y)}{||f(x,y)||}$, but some verification would be great :)

Comment: When you are not sure, writing out all components should help. It's nasty, I know, but it always works.

Comment: First find the derivative of $h(x,y) = \|f(x,y)\|^2 = f(x,y) \cdot f(x,y)$, using the product rule. Then you can get the derivative of $g(x,y) = \sqrt{h(x,y)}$ from the chain rule.

Comment: Just saw your edit. This answer is correct.

Comment: @YellowSkies: how is your link related to this question?

Comment: @Tunococ can you solve this one ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587031/derivative-of-second-norm-2-norm-l2-norm
thanx.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$. Decompose into $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$. Each $f_i$ is a real-valued function, *i.e.*, $f_i: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$. Then
$$
g(X) = \|f(X)\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X)^2}.
$$
Therefore,
$$\nabla g(X)
= \frac 12\left(\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X)^2\right)^{-\frac 12}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 2f_i(X)\nabla f_i(X)\right)
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X)\nabla f_i(X)}{\|f(X)\|_2}.
$$
This matches your answer.

If you want to write in terms of the Jacobian matrix of $f$ instead of components $f_i$, you can:
$$
\nabla g(X) = \frac{J_f(X)^T f(X)}{\|f(X)\|_2}.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: May I know if $m = 1$, e.g. $f(t) = (f_1(t), f_2(t), \cdots, f_n(t))$, then $\nabla f_i(t) = \dfrac{df_i(t)}{dt}$?

Comment: That seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the derivative of the function $ g(x, y) = \|f(x, y)\|^2 $ with respect to $x$, you can use the chain rule and the derivative of the Euclidean norm $\|x\|$ as you mentioned. Here's the correct calculation:

Given $$g(x, y) = \|f(x, y)\|^2,$$ let's find $\dfrac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}$. We have

$$
\begin{align*}
g(x, y) &= \|f(x, y)\|^2 \\
&= [f(x, y) \cdot f(x, y)] \\
&= [f(x, y)]^T \cdot f(x, y) \quad \text{ (assuming \(f\) is a column vector)} \\
\end{align*}
$$
Now, we can differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}} &= \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}} \left([f(x, y)]^T \cdot f(x, y)\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}}[f(x, y)]^T\right) \cdot f(x, y) + [f(x, y)]^T \cdot \left(\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}} f(x, y)\right) \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now, the first term is the derivative of the transpose of $f$ which is simply the transpose of the derivative of
$f$ with respect to $x$. So, it becomes $f_x^\prime(x, y)^T$.

The second term $$\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}} f(x, y)$$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, therefore the final result for $\dfrac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}$ is:

$$\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}} = f_x'(x, y)^T \cdot f(x, y) + [f(x, y)]^T \cdot f_x(x, y)$$

This expression accounts for the derivative of the norm as well as the derivative of the function $f(x, y)$ with respect to $x$.

The approach to calculate $\dfrac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}$ is similar.