# Derivative of vector-valued function's norm-squared

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

I'm trying to understand the partial chain rule and want to check my understanding.

Let $$g(\mathbf{x})=\Vert{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})}\Vert^2=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})^T\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$$

Then am I right in saying $$\frac{\text{d}g}{\text{d}\mathbf{x}}=2(\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{f})(\mathbf{x}))^T\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$$

Comment: I have never seen that definition of $\|f(x)\|$.

Comment: My apologies, I was missing a power of 2

Comment: I believe you are right.

Comment: Indeed, you can simply use the chain rule along with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291318/derivative-of-the-2-norm-of-a-multivariate-function) to get this result